# tkinter TypeError: function takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given()

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter

I'm facing a problem and I don't know from where this comes from.
As my code is too long I will only share the function generating this error and the lines where I use it (I can of course share other parts if it's necessary)

```
class Label(object):
    #constructor
    def __init__(self, data, id,  filefullpath, AGE, counter):

        self.counter = counter 
        self.filefullpath = filefullpath
        self.data = data             
        self.object_id = id
        self.data_length = len(data)
        self.AGE = AGE
        # GUI
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("CHOOSE A LABEL")
        #Create a listbox with a scrollbar
        self.listbox = Listbox(self.root)
        type = ['Indifined','a','b','c']
        for ind, val in enumerate(type):
            self.listbox.insert(ind, val)
        self.listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.save)
        self.listbox.pack()
        Button(self.root, text = "OK"  , command = self.root.destroy).pack(side = 'left')
        self.root.mainloop()


    def get_selected_label(self):
        """ get the label entered by the user """
        return(self.listbox.get(self.listbox.curselection())) 

    def save(self):
        """
        Save the label entered by the user
        """
        # get the label 
        label = self.get_selected_label()

        if len(label) > 0:
            for k in range(self.AGE +2): # plus 2 to include age=-1 and age = 0
                Informations = Get_Informations(self.data, self.filefullpath, self.counter - k)
                Id    = Informations.Id()
                age   = Informations.age()
                for ind, val in enumerate(Id):
                    if self.object_id == val:
                        age = age[ind]
                        if age <= self.AGE:
                            self.data[self.counter - k]["super_clusters"][ind]["label"] = label
                        else:
                            break
                    else:
                        pass
            for k in range(self.counter +1 , len(self.data)):
                Informations = Get_Informations(self.data, self.filefullpath,  k)
                Id    = Informations.Id()
                age   = Informations.age()
                if self.object_id in Id :
                    for ind, val in enumerate(Id):
                        if self.object_id == val :
                            age = age[ind]
                            if age != -1:
                                self.data[self.counter + k]["super_clusters"][ind]["label"] = label
                            else:
                                break
                        else:
                            pass
                else:
                    # the track disappeared
                    break
```

This is the error Python returns : as I haven't pass any argument to save when calling it I really don't understand this message.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
TypeError: save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [effbot](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111215134/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) (emphasis mine):

> Tkinter provides a powerful mechanism to let you deal with events yourself. For each widget, you can bind Python functions and methods to events.
>
> `widget.bind(event, handler)`
>
> If an event matching the event description occurs in the widget, the given handler is called **with an object describing the event**.

So the *handler* function you define in the `bind` is called with an event object. This object contains things like the widget from which the event was generated, the event type and more. Look under *The Event Object* in the effbot link for a full list.

You can of course decide to not do anything with this object, but your function *has* to accept it like:

```
def save(self, event):
```